# Get image file name from PhotoChooserTask wp 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm Working on windows phone application.in my application i have a photo upload option, for this i'm using PhotoChooserTask. here is my code,

```
 void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {


                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

                string PhotoPath = e.OriginalFileName.;

                MessageBox.Show("" + PhotoPath); // just for testing

                myImage.Source = bmp;
                myImage1.Source = bmp;

            }
        }
```

i want to get file name of the image selected from user.

```
MessageBox.Show("" + PhotoPath)
```

which display file path,something like

```
c:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Sample_image_00.jpg
```

how can i get the name of image without file path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a helper function which will extract the filename from the path:

```
public static string GetFileName(string path)
{
    return new Regex(@".+\\(\S+\.\S+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(path).Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Path.GetFileName is not supproted in WP8, it is supported in WP8.1

Comment: So then you can just do string.SubString(PhotoPath.LastIndexOf("\\")).

Comment: @ mkArtak , SubString gives error 'string' dos not contain a definition for 'Substring'

Comment: Ok, I've tried this one: new Regex(@".+\\(\S+\.\S+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(PhotoPath).Groups[1].Value

Comment: it throws error **ArgumentException** was unhandled by user code

Comment: Please fix the pattern to: @".+\\(\S+\.\S+)"

Comment: string a = new Regex(@".+\(\S+\.\S+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(PhotoPath).Groups[1].Value;

Comment: Here is a helper function:
public static string GetFileName(string path)
{
  return new Regex(@".+\\(\S+\.\S+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(path).Groups[1].Value;
}

Comment: got that exception again!

Comment: Fixed the code - for some reason when I was pasting the code in here from VS, one '\' got removed. The answer is updated now - try it. Hope this one is final.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of any in-built method, but String.Split(string) can certainly be used. The last element in the array returned by this method should be the raw file name you are expecting.